# How to find out if Queue contains last item at another position?

Tags: c#, collections

Let's have a Queue and an item which was enqueued last. What is the most efficient way to find out if the item is (not) at another position in the Queue?

The item can be remembered into another variable if it helps.

Comment: @James Michael Hare: short compute time and as little memory as possible.

Comment: @JanTuroň Unfortunately, those are two opposite goals in most cases ;)

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Agreed, which is why I always ask what the criteria of "efficient" is...

Comment: @JanTuroň: Quick question - by "last" do you mean the tail of the queue (where you Enqueue() to) or the head of the queue (where you Dequeue() from)

Comment: @JanTuroň Also - do you actually need a Queue (FIFO)?  If order is not important, there would be better options...  (I'm assuming the ordering is important, but just asking in case.)

Comment: @Jan Turoň: You might want to read up on the space/time tradeoff: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff.

Comment: @James: item which was enqueued last, as I wrote (so the tail).

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Queue is great advantage in my App (Snake): I believe the trade off for another Collection would result in too much extra code.

Comment: @Jason: The C# is managed (GC driven) and the Queue is updated very quickly, so I believe both factors will result in slowing the app in time.

Comment: `What is the most efficient way to find out if the item is (not) at another position in the Queue?` Why do you need to know this? As an author, don't you already know what you put into the queue. Or is it some kind of multi threading issue?

Comment: @L.B: To remember WHAT is inserted is not the only purpose of the Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it! I hope it helps someone else, too.

The better collection for this task is `LinkedList`

```
bool findNotLast<T>(T item, LinkedList<T> list) {
    return list.Count>1 && list.Find(item) != list.Last;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just keep a <strike>`HashSet<T>`</strike> `Dictionary<T,int>` and keep count of your items this way - when you enqueue an item in the queue you increase the count for that item (or add it to the dictionary if not present yet) - you can just check using `dictionary.ContainsKey()` *before* adding the new item to see if the item was already added, or retrieve the count for the item (>=2 in this case after insertion) - this requires of course that the item have equality defined properly.

Likewise you would have to decrease the count of an item in the dictionary when you dequeue an item from the queue, and remove it once the count reaches zero.

This approach trades additional memory cost for O(1) lookup time.

Comment: +1 Basically same answer as mine. You beat me to the punch though.

Comment: Ah yes - a `Dictionary<T,int>` for counting would be better suited for this, since you will have to count to keep track of duplicates. At that point it really has to be worth it for the `O(1)` lookup time otherwise will be much, much easier to just use the approach @JaredPar is using - no book keeping involved

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Quite a good idea, but there is quite lot of extra code. I like to write code which is clear what it does at the first glance. Here the coder is forced to think "What is the extra collection for?"

Comment: Yes that's very true - how many items do you have on average in that queue? - maybe going through the items in the queue in a linear fashion would be "good enough"

Comment: I estimate 100 in average, some 500 tops, enqueue/dequeue 10 times per second, 1-6 queues in App (Snake). Any smart idea at this point may be crucial for the App.